# Models.deleteOne is not working when trying to delete data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I've been trying to create a discord bot with a database, but when I try to delete the data when the bot leaves the server, the data doesn't get deleted at all, why?

```js
bot.on('guildDelete', guild => {
    guildSettings.deleteOne({ GuildID: guild.id })
    console.log(guild.id)
})
```

Comment: Getting any errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors. It just won't delete the data.

Comment: Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Try `guildSettings.deleteOne({ GuildID: guild.id }, (err) => console.log(err))`

Comment: It says null in the error logs, but it did delete this time. Thanks!